# How to template loop structure for use with several kernels

Tags: c++

Is there an elegant and efficient way of reusing the same loop structure for several loop kernel operations, that allows for loop kernel inlining?

I have a couple of functions that calculate some properties from some selected points on a large 3D grid. They generally follow the same pattern:

1. Determine the grid to use
2. Determine the minimum/maximum grid indices to search along each direction
3. Loop over the relevant grid indices, i.e. three nested loops over i, j, k
4. Calculate the coordinate of the grid point and check that it is within the desired region
5. If grid point is in region, calculate some property based on the grid coordinate and the grid index (i,j,k)

Currently I have at least 4 functions following this pattern, all just basically copy-pasted with point (5) changed.

However, I'm looking for a more elegant solution with less code duplication. While one could do this both by either using an OOP solution with a base class method implementing the loop and calling a virtual subclass method, or write a function taking in a pointer to a function that carries out step (5). However, I'm concerned with the overhead of calling a function from within this tight loop and would prefer the operation to be inlined. Also I'm just curious about whether there is a solution to this problem.

Here's a simplified example of what I have (in reality the functions have different return types and are more complicated):

```
double calculateA(size_t N, double x0, double dx, double max_dist) {
    double a = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        const double x = i * dx;
        if (std::abs(x - x0) < max_dist) {
            a += doInlinedOperationA(x);
        }
    }

    return a;
}

double calculateB(size_t N, double x0, double dx, double max_dist) {
    double b = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        const double x = i * dx;
        if (std::abs(x - x0) < max_dist) {
            b += doInlinedOperationB(x);
        }
    }

    return b;
}
```

Ideally I want only one place where the loop structure is defined so that it only needs to be changed one place, which hopefully should reduce the risk of bugs and the amount of tests that need to be written.

EDIT: BTW, I'm restricted to use C++11, no solutions using 14/17 features or libraries.

Comment: You could use a template and an `if constexpr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a templated function which takes a functor as the template parameter, most compilers should inline simple functions and lamdas passed as parameters. E.g.:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

double a( double d )
{
    return d * 2;
}

template <typename Kernel>
double calculate(size_t N, double x0, double dx, double max_dist, const Kernel& kernel) {
    double b = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        const double x = i * dx;
        if (std::abs(x - x0) < max_dist) {
            b += kernel(x);
        }
    }

    return b;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << calculate(1, 2, 3, 4, a) << "\n";
    std::cout << calculate(1, 2, 3, 4, [](double d){ return d*d; }) << "\n";
}
```

Clang and GCC inline everything including the `calculate` function: https://godbolt.org/z/pKRNBm

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with both your and ascheplers example which are basically identical. I think me stupid brain didn't realize that I could use the function as a template parameter - this greatly simplifies it. I am now experimenting with turning it into a variadic template such that one can pass on parameters to the Kernel function for total flexibility and it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a template with one function that will call your kernel:

```
template<typename Kernel>
struct Loops
{
    static void call(params)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < loop1; ++i)
        {
            Kernel::kernel(params);
        }
    }
};
```

And then `Kernel`:

```
struct Kernel
{
    static void kernel(params);
};
```

When I did this on a 3D seismic application (C++03), `Kernel` was usable in different `Loops`, `Loops` would also be templated on the computation type (`float` or `double`), the different types of loops would encompass different caching mechanisms, loops traversals and parallelism implementation, and `kernel` itself was also templated to accommodate features like boundary conditions.

The selection of the implementation was done through a registry mechanism that was loading plugins that held `Loops<Kernel>` instances.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds basically like just a function template.  Compilers will typically treat the template specializations as individual functions, probably giving exactly the same performance as a version with code that is copied and slightly modified.

Your example could be written:

```
template <typename Func>
double calculateOnGrid(Func&& func, size_t N, double x0, double dx, double max_dist) {
    double retval = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        const double x = i * dx;
        if (std::abs(x - x0) < max_dist) {
            retval += func(x);
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
// If "doInlinedOperationA" is a function name:
double a = calculateOnGrid(doInlinedOperationA, N, x0, dx, max_dist);

// Or using a lambda as the function:
double c = calculateOnGrid([](double x) { return std::exp(x); },
                           N, x0, dx, max_dist);
```